# media queries - separate and independent style sheet?

Tags: html, layout, mobile, css, media-queries

Using media queries in the head of the index html doc, is it possible to tell the visitors browser to use a separate style sheet independently of the original stylesheet?

Currently, what I use uses the mobile_specific stylesheet in addition to the original one which is becoming tricky to style.

```
<link type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="styles_mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

So syles_mobile.css is used in addition to styles.css. **How do I tell the browser to use ONLY "styles_mobile.css" and not both the stylesheets together?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a media query to the regular stylesheet who is the oposite of your mobile query:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_mobile.css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 480px)">
```

PS: I suggest you to use a standard order of attributes. And the `type` attribute is not required, as it has a default value of `text/css` with link and style elements and a default value of `text/javascript` on script elements.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a bit confused here. Where should I add the code you suggest? In the head of the index.htm doc? Your 1st sentence sounds like I add the code to the actual stylesheet? Can you clarify? Cheers.

Comment: @DougFirr this code is the same code as you posted, but with a media query on the `styles.css` link. You want to load `styles.css` when the screen is greater then 480px and `styles_mobile.css` when the screen is less then 480px. This is exactly what these media queries do.

Comment: looking forwards to getting home to try this out - thanks a lot!

Comment: These two media queries are not exact opposites. When the viewport is 480px wide, *both* of them will apply. You should change the first media query to `only screen and (max-device-width: 479px)`, to make the queries mutually exclusive.